# Is "Soliciting your positive response" a good way to end a formal letter?

Tags: letter

I saw that ending somewhere once, and have been using it ever since. Just wanted to confirm if there's anything wrong with adding that in a request letter for a medical leave

Comment: Given that soliciting is how prostitutes make living, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: If you think the only problem with ending a letter "please say yes!" is that it's a little casual, then this more formal version might be ok. But I don't like it at all, whether casual or formal.

Answer (score 2):

As a business manager I have received such closings before, and they irritate me. A little.

They are redundant and manipulative. Of course you are seeking positive response! What else would you be seeking?

Are you trying to make me feel guilty if I respond negatively?

A good way to end a formal letter is *"Respectfully,"*or perhaps *"Thank you in advance for any help you can offer,"* or *"Thank you for your time,"*.

Make your requests in the body of the letter. The closing line is an ending, not an opportunity to treat me like an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea.

You have hopefully provided factual evidence in support of your request. The answer rests with the recipient. Do not overstep.

Soliciting a positive response is:

1. weak: you solicit because you don't have good factual evidence to support your request
2. manipulative (mentioned in another answer)
3. disrespectful: you disregard the role of the recipient in having the freedom and power to give you whatever answer they see fit
4. rude: common courtesy would rather suggest ending with a formal greeting like 'kind regards', 'sincerely', et cetera.